# pip command is not working in vs code. i have checked everything

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip

pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pip install flask
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

i have done everythng installed python checked also
also checkd for pip i dont know why pip is not installing package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program